# /wp-admin returns "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." after adding CDN for SSL Termination?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-lightsail

After adding a CDN (CloudFront) to my environment, my admin login is still recognized, but trying to go to /wp-admin causes "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."

I tried using Incognito mode in case it was a bad cookie, but no luck. What could cause this?

I tried enabling debug modes:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

But nothing got written to `error_log` and I didn't find `debug.log`.

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to migrate then check *wp_options* table and search for *option_name* with **wp_user_roles**
In my case I  had different table names **wp_11_** which after migration changed it to **wp_** then searched *wp_options* for **%WP_11%** found a result with *option_name* that had the old table value of **wp_11_user_roles** which I changed to **wp_user_roles** and then everything was set.

[image]